# Что работает быстрее: if+include или просто if?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, какой код будет работать быстрее?

Вариант 1:

```
<?php if($model->act == 'buy'): ?>
    Человек хочет купить <?= $model->object ?>
    по цене в: <?= $model->price ?> рублей
    с площадью от: <?= $model->space1 ?> до <?= $model->space2 ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($model->act == 'sell'): ?>
    Человек хочет продать <?= $model->object ?>
    по цене от: <?= $model->price ?> до <?= $model->price2 ?> рублей
    с площадью: <?= $model->space ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Вариант 2:

```
<?php if($model->act == 'buy'): ?>
<?php include 'view_buy.php'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($model->act == 'sell'): ?>
<?php include 'view_sell.php'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`view_buy.php` и `view_sell.php` будут хранить в себе как раз тот код, который находится в первом варианте.

В первом варианте у меня весь код в одном файле, а во втором варианте у меня код вынесен в другие файлы.

Какой из вариантов будет быстрее?

Comment: `Просто if` очевидно быстрее. Удастся ли вам это замерить? Сомнительно.

Comment: `$start = microtime(true);
 .............
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);` ....... вставляете свой код вместо точек, в файлах делайте ооооооооочень много текста и измеряйте

Comment: и APC и тп. отключить не мешало бы.

Comment: Ну что в итоге?

Comment: Экономия на спичках. 100% База данных будет медленнее.  Тут больше важно возможность поддержки. Если проект разбит на файлы правильно, то поддерживать легче. Я голосую за вариант 2 хотя он и медленнее(io)!

Comment: Нет, используйте как можно меньше include. 

Я очень давно читал что вся суть заключается в том что оптимизатор исходного кода php заставляет останавливаться именно на вашем `include`.

Answer (score -2):

Если исключить, что код написан, как "курица лапой", то скорее всего разницы не будет, либо она будет очень и очень незначительна. Советую сменить стиль написания кода с кучи открывающихся и закрывающихся `<?php` ну и отойти от практики использования `endif`.

Comment: Что не так с `endif` в темплейте?

Comment: да не)код не так будет написан. Чтобы для вопроса код не переписывать, я так сделал)